# EF Core - Foreign Key Constraints using SQL Identity on Parent/Child relationship

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an already existing Database that we are trying to use EF Core with. Because of this, I have a situation where I have two tables with a modified* Parent/Child relationship are auto-incremented. Here is the EF Core code I have for them :

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<RunActualRow>(model =>
        {
            model.ToTable("RunActual");
            model.Property(a => a.ID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn().HasColumnName("ID");
            model.HasKey(a => a.ID);
            model.HasOne(d => d.RunRow)
                .WithMany(p => p.RunActualRows)
                .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.RunID})
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RunActual_Run");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RunRow>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Run");
            entity.Property(e => e.RunID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.RunID });
        });
```

So basically above, what you are seeing is that the `RunRow` is the parent entity with the `RunActualRow` being the child entity. `RunID` (`RunRow`) is the a SQL Identity generated Foreign Key to `RunActualRow`.

When I try to do an insert where I declare the parent and children in one `RunRow` object, I get an error that Entity Framework's foreign keys are missing. I am unable to set the foreign key until sql server assigns `Runs` row a PK....however, EF Core seems to not set that correctly, instead EF Core just gives me an error, and Profiler shows I'm trying to enter a `RunActual` row with an invalid FK of 0.

**Has anybody run into this specific scenario, and if so, is it a known issue or am I missing something? Do I have to make this two separate transactions?**

- WHY MODIFIED? because in this scenario we are actually not strictly enforcing that you have to have a parent to have a child.

Comment: Your `RunRow` table should not use `IDENTITY` in the foreign-key column. `IDENTITY` should not be used for foreign-keys anyway, because it's nonsensical. How on earth does your current existing database function like this?

Comment: Can you post a short, but complete repro?  There's nothing obvious in what you have posted that would cause that error.

Comment: oh trust me, I know that my current DB Structure is beyond f'd up, but it's nearly 20 years old. I was in high school when it was put together. It has foreign keys that allow null values. 

I think you misunderstood me Dai - The PRIMARY KEY is the one that is using identity.

For the Run table you have RunID as the primary key that uses SQL Identity.
For the RunActual table it uses ID as the primary key that uses SQL Identity, and has RunID as the foreign key that links it to the Run table.

I'm trying to insert a Run and RunActual in the same transaction however.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I will try to be more specific on whats happening :

I have two tables `Run` - has a RunID PK column, I have a `RunActual` table - has an ID PK column, and RunID FK. RunID (`Run`) is set by `SQL Identity` and ID (`RunActual` is as well. I try to do something very simple :

Declare RunRow with RunActual children, not setting ID or RunID fields at all, as those are set by SQL Identity and saving. `Run` goes thru fine, `RunActual` has an error complaining about a FK Constraint. I go and look at SQL Logs, and `RunID` is being set to 0.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sorry I had to edit a couple times.

Comment: Here is the code snippet :

`var row = runItem.ToNewRunRow();` ...
                `DbContext.Run.Add(row);`...
               `await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to **NOT** really be an Entity Framework Core error, although I would definitely argue that Entity Framework could handle result sets better to figure out what is actually happening or to throw a more informative error letting you know that the result set that it was looking at and it returned didn't contain the query you requested.

Thanks David for helping me figure this out - I'm not sure I would have thought to create a new table structure that mimic'd the old one close as it did to see that it does indeed work.

**The error turned out to be due to a trigger on the database** - that trigger was running a stored procedure which turned around and returned a 1 or 0 result set to say if there was an error (0 if there was no error, 1 if there was an error).

Due to this, it would cause entity framework to pick up that value (even though the resultsets column name didn't match the select statement it sent in --- which is something that could be handled better IMO) and on the child table try to use that as the foreign key. Because 0 was not a valid FK, it would error out.

Funny enough, I think that if I had gotten a 1 (Error), it would have tried to use that as the foreign key, which would have worked, because there **IS** a record with 1 as the primary key.

To conclude this - if someone runs into this issue, run your profiler, and see what Entity Framework is sending in, and what the result of the query is, if you see that you are getting multiple result sets back, take a look at the triggers being run.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  By "post a short, but complete repro", I meant something like this (but that actually fails):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
//using Microsoft.Samples.EFLogging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EFCore2Test
{

   public class RunRow
    {
        public int RunID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RunActualRow> RunActualRows { get; } = new HashSet<RunActualRow>();
    }
    public class RunActualRow
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int RunID { get; set; }
        public RunRow RunRow { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<RunRow> RunRows { get; set; }

        public DbSet<RunActualRow> RunActualRows { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        { 
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<RunActualRow>(model =>
            {
                model.ToTable("RunActual");
                model.Property(a => a.ID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn().HasColumnName("ID");
                model.HasKey(a => a.ID);
                model.HasOne(d => d.RunRow)
                    .WithMany(p => p.RunActualRows)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.RunID })
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_RunActual_Run");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<RunRow>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Run");
                entity.Property(e => e.RunID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.RunID });
            });
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=EFCoreTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }



    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();

                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter table RunActual drop constraint FK_RunActual_Run");

            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            { 

                //db.ConfigureLogging(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

                var r = new RunRow();
                db.RunRows.Add(r);

                db.SaveChanges();

                r.RunActualRows.Add(new RunActualRow());
                r.RunActualRows.Add(new RunActualRow());
                r.RunActualRows.Add(new RunActualRow());

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var count = db.RunActualRows.Count();
                Console.WriteLine($"{count} RunActualRows");
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```